# What are the sizes allowed for the displacement and scalar multiplier when specifying an address in x86 and x86_64?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

In the following example, using AT&T syntax:

```
movq 8(%rdx, %rcx, 4), %rax
```

or using Intel syntax:

```
mov rax, [rdx + 8 + rcx * 4]
```

The "displacement" is 8, and the "scalar multiplier" is 4. What are the size limitations on these immediates in x86? And what are they in x86_64?

Comment: See _Chapter 2: Instruction format_ in the _Intel instruction set reference_. TL;DR: Displacement can be 32 bit and scale factor 1,2,4 or 8.

Comment: @Jester: I was looking through that and I couldn't find it.

Comment: _Figure 2-1. Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Instruction Format_  and _Table 2-3. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the SIB Byte_. Also section _3.7.5 Specifying an Offset_ in the _Basic Architecture manual_, or specifically _Figure 3-11. Offset (or Effective Address) Computation_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jester, who answered in the comments:

> Displacement can be 32 bit and scale factor 1,2,4 or 8.